# CSS Bundle in .NET doesn't combine files, but reconstructs a list of files

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

I am using `RegisterBundles` to bundle my CSS files and server them from a virtual folder.

I have the following code in `RegisterBundles` function:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/all/")
    .Include("~/foundation/css/normalize.css",new CssRewriteUrlTransform())
    .Include("~/foundation/css/foundation.min.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform())
    .Include("~/foundation/icons/foundation-icons.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform())
    .Include("~/Content/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform())
   );
```

In my page I have the following code:

```
<%= System.Web.Optimization.Styles.Render("~/Content/all/") %>
```

The problem is that **I get a list of all the css files** instead of one combined and minified virtual path to the css. I need `CssRewriteUrlTransform` for all the css files to make sure the relative paths are maintained correctly because they exist in different folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to allow Bundled and Minified to work, you should do one of following:

1. Change compilation to `debug="false"` in web.config

```html
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" />
</system.web>
```

2. In the same file of `RegisterBundles`, add following line

```cs
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```